# A night without sleeping

Tags: single-word-requests

How many ways are there of saying that someone didn't sleep all night? In my country, it can be expressed with just an adjective or a noun; how can I say it in English?

To address the comments below:

Original language: Portuguese.

Respective (2-word) adjective: "de direta", as in "I am 'de direta'".

Respective noun: "direta", as in "Today I did a 'direta'".

Comment: I downvoted this for two reasons. First, in English there are at least dozens of ways; far too many to count. Then, it doesn't seem fair of 
igordcard to ask that, without telling us his country, and what's meant by *it can be expressed with just an adjective or a noun.*

Is *A night without sleeping* the same as *a night without sleep*, let alone *someone didn't sleep all night*? Any might be expressed with just an adjective or a noun *added* to a phrase; any language I don’t speak might have a single noun for any of them and still, won’t that adjective have to be phenomenally powerful?

Comment: It doesn't seem fair of Robbie Goodwin to downvote and assume I know all about english (except the answer to my question) without first stopping to ask a question himself.

Comment: What is it in English? OR  How can I say it in English?  ( not: How can it be .....?)

Comment: Thanks for changing that, igordcard; sorry you felt miffed.

I'm almost sorry I asked how in your country, that could be expressed with just an adjective or a noun… and without trying to start a separate discussion, I do wonder whether that's as unusual in Portuguese as it is in translation?

Either way, does anyone see a reason I can't coin two new words?

Insomnious: adjective; causing or characterised by insomnia.

Insomninight: noun; a night of insomnia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've always liked: "I had an all-nighter."

This generally refers to a night out on the town, night-time shift work, or cramming for exams. Something of that nature.

Comment: In Australian English we also use to *pull* an all-nighter, meaning to work (on a project) all night.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for.

Comment: You pull all-nighters in the U.S., too.

Comment: You can use the word "pulled". "I pulled an all nighter."

Answer (score 4):

You have a choice: an *insomnia*, a *sleepless night* (the noun is *sleeplessness*), a *wakeful night* (*wakefulness*), a *restless night* (*restlessness*).

Comment: Oh, by the way, we use an adjective too. Let me edit the question.

Comment: I don't think *insomnia* can take an article.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the word **fitful**, as in "I had a *fitful* sleep last night," which means the sleep was intermittent and not restful, not a proper night's sleep at all.

Answer (score 2):

**Insomnia** perhaps but you still need something like "I lay awake all night with insomnia" which is a bit redundant.

Comment: Yes, the cause doesn't need to be insomnia though.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the word **white night** used for this, but I think this is taken from other languages.

Comment: I certainly would have no clue what you meant by "white night" without a lot of further context. "White knight" is a set phrase in English. "White night" is not.

Comment: It's used in Italian, passare la notte in bianco = (literally) to pass a night in white, i.e. Nowadays understood to stay up all night; but the true meaning of this expression lies deep in medieval history.

Comment: I think I was thinking of the French "nuit blanche"